# How to configure Java Hibernate for Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Hibernate + Java + Jersey + MYSql and it's working fine on local machine. However I am unable to create a connection to MySql on Google Cloud.

I think MYSql configuration and instance creation is fine on Google Cloud, but I am unable to pass all configuration through hibernate properties. See here what Google's sample code:

```
// The configuration object specifies behaviors for the connection pool.
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

// Configure which instance and what database user to connect with.
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
config.setUsername(DB_USER); // e.g. "root", "postgres"
config.setPassword(DB_PASS); // e.g. "my-password"

// For Java users, the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory can provide authenticated connections.
// See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory for details.
config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");

// ... Specify additional connection properties here.
// ...

// Initialize the connection pool using the configuration object.
DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Now I dont know how to pass `cloudSqlInstance` and `socketFactory` in Hibernate. Here what I tried to pass these parameters but it's not working:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://google/pashumandi_db?cloudSqlInstance=pashuserver:asia-south1:mysql-instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
hibernate.connection.username = abc_user
hibernate.connection.password = 12345678
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Could you please let me know what is correct hibernate configuration to connect with MySql on Google Cloud? Thanks.

Comment: Did you configure the Google Cloud DB to allow an external connection from your IP address?

Comment: Hey, I'm seeing that you managed to connect with Hibernate as you made another question about the certificates and such. Could you fix the issue?

If not, let me know and we will look further into it as I'm curious about the connectivity of Hibernate with Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME for the instance on the Instance details page on Google Cloud Console. It uses the format PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID, and is used to identify the Cloud SQL instance you are connecting to.

To enable a local TCP port, add the following to your project's app.yaml file:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:<PORT>
```

Then here is my hibernate.properties file:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:PORT_NUMBER_IN_YAML_FILE
hibernate.connection.username = DB_USERNAME
hibernate.connection.password = DB_PASSWORD
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.default_schema = DATABASE_NAME
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

For more details you can visit: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud you can select your DB instance and then under “CONNECTIONS” you can select to allow connections from Public IP addresses and then add your machine’s IP address to the list of addresses authorizes to make a connection. From there all you need to do is use the public IP address of your DB instance in the URL.

Comment: I understand your point, may you tell me how to pass "cloudSqlInstance"?